# Push config for OpenVPN Connect with GPO

Tags: windows-10, openvpn, group-policy

I'm trying to push OpenVPN Connect msi with a config to some domain connected computers

But i can figure out how to make the client pick up the config
I copied it to the profile directory of the installation and added it in the openvpn-connect.json in the user directory, but no luck with getting it to show up in the connect menu in the client.

Is this even doable, or do i miss anything?
This page with how to config the client with GPO doesnt metion anything about the config itself:
https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/active-directory-deploying-the-access-server-connect-client-via-gpos/